# Can I use Tensorboard to manage-fjobs and visualize learning on non-Tensorflow algoithrms? (e.g. Scikit?)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tensorflow

I am still searching for a great tool that manages jobs and visualizes learning from my models. Tensorboard is obviously one option given it's massive support.

But is it possible to organize jobs and visualize learning on tensorboard for algorithms not from the TF library?

Answer (score 0):

For logging values with TensorBoard (without running TensorFlow), you can use the [tensorboard logger](https://pypi.org/project/tensorboard_logger/) library.